# ADO - Can you avoid hardcoding a task output variable name in a YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a custom task that returns a variable with a dynamic name based on the environment I'm working on (don't have access to that custom task and can't update it in any way). Since that variable contains a secret, I would like to reference it directly in another task.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

Any idea on how to get around this?

```
variables:
     environmentOutputVariable: "dev"
----
    - task       : CustomTask@1
      name       : CustomTask
      inputs     :
        input: $(input_variable)
        

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
           targetType: 'inline'
           script: |
              echo "$(CustomTask.$environmentOutputVariable)"
              echo "$(CustomTask.${{ variables.environmentOutputVariable }}"
```